# Unexpected behaviour of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: xcode, macos

I am making a movie of screen using **AVCaptureMovieFIleOutput**, but it is showing unexpected behaviour.

Like, if I am sending the cropRect parameter the movie captured is fine, but if I making the movie of whole screen instead of movie file it is showing a folder. How can I get rid of that?

**Code is :**

```
    // Create a capture session
    mSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // If you're on a multi-display system and you want to capture a secondary display,
    // you can call CGGetActiveDisplayList() to get the list of all active displays.
    // For this example, we just specify the main display.
    CGDirectDisplayID displayId = kCGDirectMainDisplay;

    // Create a ScreenInput with the display and add it to the session
    input = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID:displayId];

    [input setCropRect:rect];

    if (!input) {
        mSession = nil;
        return;
    }
    if ([mSession canAddInput:input])
        [mSession addInput:input];

    // Create a MovieFileOutput and add it to the session
    mMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    if ([mSession canAddOutput:mMovieFileOutput])
        [mSession addOutput:mMovieFileOutput];

    // Start running the session
    [mSession startRunning];

    // Delete any existing movie file first
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[destPath path]])
    {
        NSError *err;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[destPath path] error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error deleting existing movie %@",[err localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    // Start recording to the destination movie file
    // The destination path is assumed to end with ".mov", for example, @"/users/master/desktop/capture.mov"
    // Set the recording delegate to self
    [mMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:destPath recordingDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to use `setSessionPreset` property.

Default value of `sessionPreset` is `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` and it does not work with the full screen capture. Will have to provide any other preset for that.